# Lentitud al crear maskedTextBox dinamicos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un proyecto que cuando le qiero agragar por ejemplo una matriz de maskedTextBox de 21x21 dentro de un groupBox lo hace lento... Quisiera saber si esto es algo normal debido a que estoy instanciando recursos en tiempo de ejecucion o es que hay una manera de hacerlo sin que sea tan lento... Aqui les dejo el codigo de instancia de maskedTextBox

Las variables M y N son el resultado de otra ventana emergente para inicializar una matriz MxN

```
 int M, N;
 M = insertarMatriz.getM();
 N = insertarMatriz.getN(); // insertar matriz es una interfaz para introducir dos elementos

//itero por las filas y columnas
for (int i = 1; i <= M - 1; i++)
{
     BtnAddFila_Click(sender, e);
}
for (int i = 1; i <= N - 1; i++)
{
     BtnAddCol_Click(sender, e);
}
private void BtnAddCol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x, y;
        y = textBoxesMatrix[0, indF].Location.Y;
        x = textBoxesMatrix[0, indF].Location.X + 35;


        btnAddFila.Location = new Point(x + 30, y);

        indF++;

        for (int i = 0; i <= indC; i++)
        {
            y = textBoxesMatrix[i, indF - 1].Location.Y;
            x = textBoxesMatrix[i, indF - 1].Location.X + 35;
            MaskedTextBox maskedTextBoxFilaNew = new MaskedTextBox
            {
                Text = "",
                Mask = maskedTextBoxFila.Mask,
                Location = new Point(x, y),
                Visible = true,
                Height = maskedTextBoxFila.Height,
                Width = maskedTextBoxFila.Width,
                Enabled = true,
                BeepOnError = true,
                TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
                Parent = matrixGroupBox
            };

            textBoxesMatrix[i, indF] = maskedTextBoxFilaNew;
        }
  }
```

El otro boton hace exactamente lo mismo...Alguna sugerencia??

Comment: Partamos de la base que si llamas a un metodo con la firma de un evento en un `for` arrancamos mal. Si vas a iterar crea un funcion, pero que no se un click de ningun control. Los for de `M` y `N` en que contexto los invocas ?

Comment: veo que creas una matriz, pero en que momento llevas esto al groupbox ?

Comment: no evaluaste otras alternativas como usar un TableLayoutPanel o quizas el Repeater ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini la matriz es simplemente un arreglo bidimensional de maskedTextBox... y al groupBox simplemente le digo que es su padre eso me funciona muy bien y a que te refieres con "Partamos de la base que si llamas a un metodo con la firma de un evento en un for arrancamos mal" pudieras explicarme..

Comment: el que yo llame a un eventoClick hace que sea mas lento el proceso de la funcion??

Comment: No se si sea la causa, pero si programas de esa forma es un sintoma de una incorrrecta programacion. Sigue sin quedar claro en que contexto estan los for de M y N, podrias editar la pregunta y poner dentro de donde esta ese codigo?

Comment: como le indicas al groupBox que una arreglo bidimensional es su padre ?

Comment: no se lo indico el arreglo es solo para despues sacar esos valores que el usuario introdujo recorriendolo y asi formar una matriz de numeros